# TypeScript object properties being nullified

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to pass instances of a model class (Message) as an argument to a method on a component class in Angular. It has 6 properties, but only one property needs to be populated at this point in the code. For some reason, once the object is passed in, *all* the properties become null. Is there some kind of arcane JS behavior going on here that I'm not aware of? Thanks.

The instance property of `message` on the component is an instance of the `Message` class

```
export class Message {
  constructor(
    public messageId: number,
    public messageTicketId: number,
    public messageProfileId: number,
    public messageContent: string,
    public messageDateTime: number,
    public messageIsStageTwo: number
  ) {}
}
```

and is defined like this

```
  message: Message = new Message(null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

The object is populated by a model-driven form, as follows (given the impossibility of nesting form, as well as a requirement for two-way binding, I am using a model-driven form to individually map the inputs to properties, and submitting this object with click event on a regular button)

```
<form name="ticketForm" #ticketForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendTicket()">
<!-- main body of form here-->
  <label for="messageContent">Message:</label>
  <textarea id="messageContent" name="messageContent" [(ngModel)]="message.messageContent" #messageContent="ngModel"></textarea>
  <button type="button" (click)="sendMessage()">Save</button>
<!-- .... rest of form here -->
```

```
// at this point, this.message is an object with one property set to a string
// so then I call queueMessage(this.message); like this:

  sendMessage(): void {
    if(this.ticketId) {
      this.createMessage(this.message);
    } else {
      this.queueMessage(this.message);
    }
  }
```

and queueMessage looks like this:

```
queueMessage(message: Message): void {
  console.log(message); // is an object with all null properties
  this.messageQueue.push(message);
}
```

Comment: It could be how the functions and the `this` reference is referencing `message`. Would be possible to add the invocation code and how `this.message` is being declared in the first place?

Comment: I've added this information, thanks

Comment: We'd need to see how you are binding the form to the Message object and the Message class definition.

Comment: Please add all the relevant code.

Comment: I've added the form and Message code

Comment: @Kai, Could you create plunker, because with the code you have provided I could not recreate your issue...